# Selecting the Correct NHibernate Package in NuGet to Get Lazy Loading Support

Tags: nhibernate, nuget

I am using NHibernate in a project, and I am trying to add it to my solution using NuGet.  When I search for NHibernate in the package manager I see three different results:

- NHibernate, version 3.2.0.4000, "NHibernate is a mature, open source object-relational mapper for the .NET framework. "
- NHibernate.Castle, version 3.1.0.4000, "This package enables the ability to use lazy-loading with Castle dynamic-proxy."
- NHibernate.LinFu, version 3.1.0.4000, "This package enables the ability to use lazy-loading with LinFu dynamic-proxy."

I would like to use lazy loading in this application, but the most recent package with a version of 3.2 makes no mention of it.  Do I need to download either the .Castle or .LinFu versions to get lazy loading support, even though they appear to be older versions of NHibernate?  Does NHibernate 3.2 incorporate lazy loading without requiring the need for the external Castle or LinFu proxy implementations?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to download anything besides NH 3.2.

NHibernate 3.2 removes almost all dependencies, including the ones for lazy load, now it comes with a built-in bytecode provider.